Saving callback refs into a context to then use within another component
I have a long list component that consists of some big elements. These elements can trigger a notification in a sidebar. I have a sidebar in which I want to be able to scroll to a particular notification: one that triggered this notification. Hence the question from the title:
Can I store some long list of refs within a context? To then use that list to access a ref of a particular element from my list and simply call .scrollIntoView(). I've tried:
I created a context like this:
import { createContext, createRef, useContext } from "react";

const ElementRefsContext = createContext();

const elementRefs = createRef({});

export const ElementRefsProvider = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <ElementRefsContext.Provider value={elementRefs}>
      {children}
    </ElementRefsContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useElementRefsContext = () => {
  return useContext(ElementRefsContext);
};


function LongListOfBigElements() {
    const { elementRefs } = useElementRefsContext();

    return (
        <>
            {messages?.map((message, index) => (
                <BigElement
                      ref={(el) => {
                          const messageId = message.message_id;
                          const elementId = index;
                              if (elementRefs) {
                                  console.log(workDropdownRefs);
                                  if (!elementRefs.current[messageId]) {
                                   elementRefs.current[messageId] = {};
                              }
                              elementRefs.current[messageId][
                                elementId
                              ] = el;
                            }
                          }}/>)
        </>



Okay so since you’ve populated the elementRefs this way, how do you plan to use it? Also side note. return a value to ref from that arrow function.

There's a button within the Element that creates a notification and passes down the messageId as well as the index to it. Ideally, I want to access the particular ref using refs[messageId][index] and call .scrollIntoView()

Technically, yes you can, but it is something that has to be implemented carefully. It is a minefield in that you can easily create memory leaks since the context can now hold a reference to an element even after it has been potentially removed from the DOM,  which would prevent it from being garbage collected.
When the ref callback is called where el is null, it should unset the ref from the context. Your code does this, but holding mutable references is a bit error prone.
However, it's probably quite a lot easier to lean on simple markup to achieve this. If BigElement assigns messageId (or something derived from it) to some HTML attribute like id. Then, when scrolling, you can simply look up that element and scroll to it using querySelector or otherwise.
This may sound like I'm suggesting hacky code that breaks component encapsulation, but this is possibly the right thing to do here. After all # fragment URLs allow referencing any DOM element ID by default to scroll to it.
If you really don't want to do that, then you could instead store in the context the activeMessageId. Then, each BigElement would be passed its own messageId via props. Inside of BigElement a useEffect with activeMessageId from the context in the deps array could be used to check if the activeMessageId is equal to the passed props.messageId. If it is, then a local ref could be used with scrollIntoView().
When activeMessageId is updated, the appropriate BigElement will respond.
No storing of DOM elements or refs would be needed outside of the component that owns that DOM element. Which both avoids leaks and reduces complexity.

Apologies I stated your code didnt handle the null ref, but actually it does. Regardless, best avoided. Edited.

I really don't know why I did not even think of just making a simple querySelector like you suggested. I've been debugging deep re-renders for a big app this whole week, I guess it's time to touch grass. Thank you!

To be honest reaching out to a DOM node owned by some other components should definitely raise alarm bells. But I think here you could argue its leveraging the web platform. You could even instead of using scrollIntoView, actually change URL fragment. Or look into hooking smooth scroll into URL fragment change. Then there's always the alternative method where you avoid refs in context if really needed.

Makes sense. Simplicity over unnecessary complexity
